# Python Pandas put each column to a new row

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to make new rows out of existing rows with splitting data.  I currently have(Notice random spaces exist between quotes and numbers sometimes)

```
FIT-1401,"0327.0001, 0327.0002"
FIT-1056," 0361.0001, 0361.0004, 3000.0010"
FIT-831,1120.0009
FIT-491,1207
```

I would like exactly as formatted without the space..

```
FIT-1401,0327.0001
FIT-1401,0327.0002
FIT-1056,0361.0001
FIT-1056,0361.0004
FIT-1056,3000.0010
FIT-831,1120.0009
FIT-491,1207
```

Currently my code is able to split it, but having trouble getting to this clean format.

```
    #THIS FUNCTION WILL SEPERATE TC NUMBERS INTO SEPERATE COLUMNS from the jira query
#####Cleans Open CSV######

dfcleancsv = pd.read_csv('InitialQuerydataOpen.csv', sep=",", dtype='object')

dfcleancsv.columns = ['KEYS', 'ENV']


#Takes all the data after TC
s = dfcleancsv['ENV']


#removes column with junk information

##TODO CLEAN UP COLUMNS with spaces to new rows
dfcleancsv = dfcleancsv.join(s.apply(lambda x: Series(x.split('TC'))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """FIT-1401,"0327.0001, 0327.0002"
FIT-1056," 0361.0001, 0361.0004, 3000.0010"
FIT-831,1120.0009
FIT-491,1207"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), index_col=0, header=None)
```

#### Solution

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace(' ', '').str.split(',', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True)
print pd.DataFrame(df1).to_csv(header=None)

FIT-1401,0327.0001
FIT-1401,0327.0002
FIT-1056,0361.0001
FIT-1056,0361.0004
FIT-1056,3000.0010
FIT-831,1120.0009
FIT-491,1207
```

#### Explanation

- `str.replace` gets rid of spaces
- `str.split` expands comma separated values into their own columns
- `stack` pushes all columns into rows
- `reset_index` cleans up residual index level
- `pd.DataFrame` wrapper enables me to `to_csv` without a file argument so I can print to screen

Comment: My printout doesnt give the second column ..0     FIT-4432
1     FIT-4429
2     FIT-4329
3     FIT-4321
4     FIT-4319
5     FIT-4317
6     FIT-4316
7     FIT-4310
8     FIT-4307
9     FIT-4306
10    FIT-4304
11    FIT-4303
12    FIT-4266
13    FIT-4265
14    FIT-4262
15    FIT-4204
16    FIT-4184
17    FIT-4075
18    FIT-4073
19    FIT-4072

Comment: I added my setup.  try to validate from what I setup.  If you get what I got, then the `df` I'm working with is somehow different than what you have.  This would be a good example of why its important to provide the code you used to create your objects.

Comment: As my answer is, assuming the `df` I'm manufacturing, it produces exactly what you asked for.  The problem lies in your pasting the text of what your `df` looks like without posting a snippet that produces it.  The exercise of trying to create that snippet in reduced form may very well uncover your problem.